# System not working as expected after switching system from Ubuntu to Debian

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, boot, debian

So I decided to switch from Ubuntu to Debian last night, but I've had a slew of problems and mistakes. The laptop is a Lenovo E580, and OS I have in installed is Linux buster/sid x86_64, according to neofetch.

The biggest being that I installed i386 instead of amd64, as this is a new laptop and is 64 bit. I also accidentally somehow installed GNOME 3 when I wanted LXDE. Upon installation I have been completely unable to get my Wi-Fi drivers working, most tutorials on the internet are years old and feature outdated packages and commands, and `unetbootin` is refusing to install.

I have no USB flash drives or DVDs to use a boot loader, it needs to be done from the drive itself.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this done, and then maybe even deduce how to get my wifi drivers working? I would post the Wi-Fi driver on this laptop but I've been mostly unable to use any of the normal commands I’d use to find it; command line keeps saying they don't exist.

The  `lspci` output:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 
802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8822BE 
802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [17aa:b024] 
Kernal driver in use: r8822be 
Kernal modules: r8822be
```

Comment: I get a bunch of stuff that I can't copy-paste, but it reads 05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [17aa:b024] Kernal driver in use: r8822be Kernal modules: r8822be

Comment: If you have an unallocated space on your hard drive you can use it to install debian through chroot. Also you can use the PXE boot (netboot) if you have another PC.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -rv r8822be` then `sudo modprobe -v r8822be aspm=0` then `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1761693

Comment: The first and second commands say FATAL: Module r8822be not found.

Comment: You can install the missing drivers from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new#installation-instruction. See the install instruction then run the above commands.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment of installation has one specific window to configure your connection, it fails in the most of time because needs a third part non-free firmware. It happens with WI-FI connection.

You need to installing manually a package firmware-iwlwifi, you can search for "iwlwifi debian stretch", for example, if you uses this version, and your model of computer that must appear in some forum or install a generic firmware. Try the architecture that you have install.

Follow the link where you can to download form other device and transfer via USB connection:
https://pkgs.org/download/firmware-iwlwifi

To isntall:

```
dpkg -i <package_name>
```

To remove the package and erase configuration files

```
dpkg --purge <package_name>
```

After, when you has access to the internet you'll need to configure the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` to let the OS know which repositories will be used by the high level package management, APT.

https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Don't worry, it's normal. Debian is a solid distro but has more steps to be fully up and running if you compare to Ubuntu.

**PS**: I saw later the lspci output. See that in this case (a problem with Debian): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382939/debian-9-rtl8188ce-wifi-driver-problem

Comment: I tried downloading from the link you requested with "sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi" but I got "E: package 'firmware-iwlwifi' has no installation candidate' It says about that the package is not available and that it might be missing, obsolete, or only available from another source.

Comment: Your APT doesn't will work without set up sources.list and internet connection. You need download the package at the first link, and install it with "dpkg -i <package_name>", where package name is the name of package downloaded by you. You will need to be logged with super user, text "su" and press enter, infom the password, so go on with installation of firmware.

Comment: I see later the lspci output. See that in this case, @Sagarmatha: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382939/debian-9-rtl8188ce-wifi-driver-problem